# How to get a list of all tags

Tags: feature-request

A  [recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123314/whats-another-way-to-say-problem-area) has been retagged with “professions” as a tag.   Previously, only one [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122067/differences-between-servant-maid-page-and-attendant) had that tag.  Although I don't personally see a need for that particular tag (and a hundred other little-used tags) I realize that personal preferences are not the best basis for deleting or changing tags.  If a complete text list of tags were available, it might be easier to find a suitable and more frequently used tag, and thus provide adequate reason for removing some of the little-used tags, or recording them as synonyms of others.

Instead of a complete text list being available, [the list](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) (as I see it) is broken up into 22 hard-to-search small pages of about 36 entries each.  The three sort orders – popular, name, new – and the single-term search box do not provide adequate access to the list of tags.

Does anyone know how to get a list of all tags, in one piece instead of dozens?

Answer (score 3):

Courtesy of [another user](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/8282) I present the following...

http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/136950/full-list-of-tags